# Yet another RMI Issue

Tags: java, rmi, java-7, javac

Before you said that, yes, I know, there are a lot of threads which cover the same issue here on Stackoverflow, but any of those solved my problem. My problem is using the RMI interface (that is mandatory for my purposes) in two distinct computers, where one provides the RMI object (Server) and one asks for the Stub and obtains a Proxy. My code is the exact copy of the one provided by the Java 7 Reference Manual by Oracle and edited by Oracle Press:

**IRmi.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface IRmi extends Remote {
    double add() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**RmiImpl.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class RmiImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IRmi {
    public RmiImpl() throws RemoteException {}

    public double add() { double d = 5.0; return d; }
}
```

**Server.java**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.rmi.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        try {
            RmiImpl ri = new RmiImpl();
            Naming.rebind("Server",ri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Err");
        }
    }

}
```

**Client.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        try {
            IRmi itf = (IRmi)Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.0.8/Server");
            System.out.println(itf.add());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I compile with:

```
javac IRmi.java
javac RmiImpl.java
rmic RmiImpl
javac Client.java
javac Server.java
```

After that passage, I copy all the classes on both the client and the server, and then I run `rmiregistry` on the same folder where the classes were transfered. Assuming that in my local lan (192.168.0.0/255) there are two machines, where the client is 192.168.0.3 and the server 192.168.0.8 I run on those machine respectively `java client` and `java Server`, where the Client returns me the following error:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connessione rifiutata
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at RmiImpl_Stub.add(Unknown Source)
    at Client.main(Client.java:8)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connessione rifiutata
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 5 more
```

For instance, In another test I've also tried to implement the server with this following code:

```
    try {
        RemImpl obj = new RemImpl(this.serv);
        if (this.ob_list.size()>0) {
            for (Observer ob: ob_list) {
                obj.addObserver(ob);
            }
        }
        this.myrec = (Rem) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 9999);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(9999);
        registry.rebind(this.serv, this.myrec);
        //this.has_error = false;
        System.out.println("Binded as "+this.serv);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        System.err.println("Remote exception catched: " + e.getMessage());
        //this.has_error = true;
        this.myrec = null;
    }
```

and the client with the other following code:

```
    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
        this.myrec = (Rem) registry.lookup(service);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and, in this case, the client returns me the following and different error:

```
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
ERROR
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.send(Unknown Source)
    at rmi.lowlevel.NullSenderPolicy.send(NullSenderPolicy.java:81)
    at message.policy.old.BroadcastSenderPolicy.single_send(BroadcastSenderPolicy.java:104)
    at message.policy.old.AtomicBroadcastSender.fifo_send(AtomicBroadcastSender.java:54)
    at message.policy.old.AtomicBroadcastNode.fifo_send(AtomicBroadcastNode.java:131)
    at elements.testunit.TestPairBroadcastNodes.main(TestPairBroadcastNodes.java:20)
```

At this point I don't know which way to turn. Thanks in advance for any other kind suggestion.

Comment: Are your classes inside of a package?

Comment: a) Oracle didn't put its examples in any package.
b) Yes, my code (the second example) was inside a package.

Comment: where are your classes going? what folder? after you compile

Comment: a) All the classes are in the same folder, in both client and server, and in this very same folder I start the rmiregistry
b) For the second example, I use Eclipse, and I add `${workspace_loc:Project}/bin` as a working directory for the `rmiregistry`, and I add the `-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${workspace_loc:Project}/Project/` argument for both client and server classes

Comment: See my answer. Don't run your rmiregistry from the package dir, instead from the `bin` or `src` (wherever your compiled files are) then run with the `packagename.ClassName`. See if that works

Comment: As I said, the main issue doesn't concern the packages at all, since I obtain the same errors as before (yes, I've done as you said) and already Oracle published its code packages-less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem was lately solved by adding the `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.x` argument on both client and server. Thanks for all the advices.

Answer (score 1):

The connection refusal seems to be a case of [item A.1 in the RMI FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain).

The NoSuchObjectInTable problem is because you're looking up the wrong Registry. You created it on port 9999 but you're looking up a different one. This can be cured by calling getRegistry(serverHost, 9999) in the client.

You should also make the Registry reference static in the server JVM.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I've changed the second client to `Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(hos,9999);`, but the `java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table` error is still there! :(

Comment: It will still be there if you use Naming.lookup() as in your first example.

Comment: Well, even with `Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.0.8",9999); /*...*/ Rem.class.cast(r.lookup(ser));`, I obtain the same error. And even more, now I've also tried to make the Registry static at service level. Same error again. Maybe I'm a n00b, but the object returned by `j = (IRmi) r.lookup(ser)` is of a $Proxy type, and I get the error while I try to invoke the method here defined.... I wonder why the Proxy returns such kind of error when the add() method is invoked on client side.